# trigger keypress on overlay without clicking on it?

Tags: javascript

`keypress` is not get triggered on an overlay, after clicking on the overlay it works. Is there a way to trigger `keypress` without clicking on the overlay.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: your question is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have focus on the overlay or set the keylistneer closer to the body element.

Just set focus using yourElwment.focus() and it should work.